# Python String Formatting

Tags: python, string, format

I am reading from an informix database on windows server via python and pyobdc.

Retrieving a row with decimal values I get something like this:

```
    [(Decimal("0.99"), ), (Decimal("0.0"), ), (Decimal("113.84"), ),.....]
```

It is no problem to get rid of the Word decimal but I cant figure out how to delete all the braces and " I dont need so that I can calculate the sum of this list.

What is the best way to do it in python?

Comment: You aren't "getting rid of words" because you presumably don't have a string; you have a data structure there. The string you show there is just a text representation of the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just calculate sum of Decimal objects, they have `__sum__` method.

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> a = [(Decimal("0.99"), ), (Decimal("0.0"), ), (Decimal("113.84"), )]
>>> sum(i[0] for i in a) #Because they're in a tuple
Decimal('114.83')
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, the `from decimal import Decimal` isn't necessary, since the `Decimal` objects have already been instantiated.

Comment: @Chinmay it's necessary to set up an example from scratch though :)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem isn't that you have the Decimal("xyz") but that each value is in a tuple. So, you need to get the values out of the tuples so you can sum them.

```
a = [(Decimal("0.99"), ), (Decimal("0.0"), ), (Decimal("113.84"), ),.....]
b = sum(number[0] for number in a)
```

Comment: Does the `Decimal()` type support addition or does he first have to cast it to a `float`?

Comment: `Decimal` supports addition just fine.

Comment: @Brandon: they support addition. Casting to a float is a bad idea, as then you lose precision.